# Django-cms plugin mptt filtering by node to display new subtree, based on config

Tags: django-models, django-cms, django-filter

I am trying to implement a plugin for django-cms that shows a tree of of links. What I want to do is filter this tree based on what config the user chooses in my CMS. So based on the node he chooses in the config I want to be able to display only that sub-tree.

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin

class Section(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class SectionConfig(CMSPlugin):
    root_shown = models.ForeignKey("Section")
    title = models.CharField(default="Usefull Links", max_length=25)
```

Here is my cms_plugins.py:

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from links_plugin.models import Section, SectionConfig

class LinksPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    name = _("Links Tree Plugin")
    model = SectionConfig
    render_template = "links.html"
    cache = False

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context['instance'] = instance
        context['nodes'] = Section.objects.all()
        return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(LinksPlugin)
```

and here is my templates/links.html

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
    <h1>Liens Utiles</h1>
    {% load mptt_tags %}
    <ul class="root">
        {% recursetree nodes %}
            <li>
                {{ node.name }}
                {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                    <ul class="children">
                        {{ children }}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endrecursetree %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

So my issue is giving the right set of nodes to my context. So in my cms_plugins.py id like to change

```
context['nodes'] = Section.objects.all()
```

to a filter that would build the subtree based on my

```
root_shown = models.ForeignKey("Section")
```

The problem is I don't know how to use the FK to reference my Section object and find my new root Section. From then I thought that I could use the get_descendants(include_self=True) to rebuild this new sub-tree and display that list of nodes. Am I wrong? How to I reference my desired node?

If possible ELI5

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something like this:

```
contect['nodes'] = instance.root_shown.get_descendants(include_self=True)
```